# Spring + xls и doc

Tags: java, spring, office, apache-poi

Не получается загрузить файлы xls и doc(старый Office) файл загружается, но он пустой и выскакивает сообщение конфлик версий. С xlsx и docx все нормально. Вот код:

```
@GetMapping("getFileData/{id}")
public void downloadFile(@PathVariable long id,HttpServletResponse response)  

 {
    log.info("\n\nGET: /user/getFileData/"+id);

    File file = service.getFile(id);

    byte[]fileBytes = null; 

    try(OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream()) {
        if(file.getType().split("/")[0].equals("image")){
            fileBytes = service.loadImageFromFile(file.getFileName());
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType(file.getType());
            response.getOutputStream().write(fileBytes);
        }else if(file.getFileName().split("\\.")[1].equals("pdf")){
            fileBytes = service.loadFileFromFile(file.getFileName());
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType(file.getType());
            response.getOutputStream().write(fileBytes);
        }else if(file.getFileName().split("\\.")[1].equals("xls")){
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="
                    +file.getFileName().split("/")[2]);
            response.setContentType(file.getType());
            HSSFWorkbook workbook =  service.loadXLS(file.getFileName());
            response.reset();
            response.getOutputStream().write(workbook.getBytes());
        }else if(file.getFileName().split("\\.")[1].equals("xlsx")){
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="
                    +file.getFileName().split("/")[2]);
            response.setContentType(file.getType());
            XSSFWorkbook workbook =  service.loadXLSX(file.getFileName());
            workbook.write(os);
            os.flush();
        }else if(file.getFileName().split("\\.")[1].equals("doc")){
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="
                    +file.getFileName().split("/")[2]);
            response.setContentType(file.getType());
            HWPFDocument document =  service.loadDOC(file.getFileName());
            document.write(os);
            os.flush();
        }else if(file.getFileName().split("\\.")[1].equals("docx")){
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="
                    +file.getFileName().split("/")[2]);
            response.setContentType(file.getType());
            XWPFDocument document =  service.loadDOCX(file.getFileName());
            document.write(os);
            os.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("\n\n"+e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

        log.info("\nReturn: OK");
}
```

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но советую вам посмотреть на **Apache Commons IO**, в частности на `FilenameUtils.getBaseName()` и `FilenameUtils.getExtension()`

Comment: @V.Makhnutin File - это нестандартный, а мой класс.